# Site.com error when attempting to add domain name

Tags: site.com

We are trying to migrate an existing domain to Site.com.  We've followed the instructions outlined here:

http://na10.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/siteforce_domains_migrating.htm

However, when attempting to add the domain to Site.com we get the error: "Error: The domain and path combination is already in use. Enter a different domain name or path and try again"

Now, the DNS is not set up with an DNS A record as far as I know, just a CNAME record. What would be the migration process for such a set up? And could it be causing such an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you crmprogdev for your help.

I did eventually open a case with Salesforce support regarding this issue. The problem is that the domain that we are attempting to migrate to Site.com is already associated with a Force.com site. I failed to mention that in my original question because I did not know that. Or rather, I did know it but had forgotten about it.

So, we have to first deactivate the Force.com site, then change the DNS CNAME record to point to the Site.com URL, and then we should be able to add the domain to Site.com.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that with us Sean. That would completely explain the error message and is useful information to know should anyone ask in the future! :) Please wait a day or two and mark your answer as the solution to your question as you don't have enough rep yet to do so for a couple days.

Comment: Deactivating the Force.com site first and then adding the CNAME worked, though it did not prevent significant downtime.

Answer (score 1):

Until the Domain name has a DNS record that points to a Salesforce server, they won't be able to host your site, instead they'll only be able to link to it from an existing host. You can check the status of any domain by going to http://www.whois.com/whois/ and entering your company's domain name(s). That will tell you what DNS its pointed to, who the owner is, etc.

**Edited to add**

If the site isn't currently pointed to a DNS server, you'll need to fill out the forms to have the DNS server registration (and ISP registration too if there won't be any outside hosting) transferred and pointed to a Salesforce server. If that needs done, I suggest you contact Salesforce support. In my experience, ISP's often don't get in much of a hurry when it comes to transferring control of domain registristrations.

**Additional:** The name should be the same as the URL of the domain name. E.G. `www.mycompany.com`, `www.mycompany.biz` or in the situation where there's no `www` used in the URI, something like `mycompany.com`. Regardless, you want it to be the same as your current web URL address that you plan to port over. The SF documentation recommends adding variants on the Domain name to allow for spelling errors on the part of users. I'd suggest you try entering some variations that are close to your domain name to see if that gets you there.

It also occurred to me to ask, have you checked to make certain that YOU have the `Site.com Publisher User` field enabled on **Your Own Personal User** detail page in Setup as an Admin AND, according to the documentation, also have Publisher Role assigned at the site level? If not, you won't be able to set up your site.

If those things are all in place and it's still a "no go", I'm totally out of ideas. Unless someone else has suggestions for you, then your next step would seem to be to open a case with support.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The domain is already registered and pointing to an existing non-Site.com site. The Salesforce instructions suggest you can migrate a site to a Site.com site by first adding a DNS TXT record, which should then make the domain available for adding to Site.com and you can publish the site without making it live yet. Then, when you want to go live, you add the CNAME record that points the domain to the Salesforce server. Unfortunately, those instructions do not seem to be working.

Comment: I am working with another party that actually has access to make DNS changes. I believe they added 1 TXT record 'containing' the organization id and named it 'www' Is there a specific name you must give the TXT record?

Comment: I was able to confirm that the TXT record name is the name of the domain, but same error.